# Phonegap build failed with an exception for task ':packageArmv7Debug'

Tags: cordova

I have all the relevant SDKs and build tools installed for Android but the gradle build is failing.

```
Execution failed for task ':packageArmv7Debug'.
> Failed to add platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/resources-armv7-debug.ap_
```

I've made sure I'm running the latest phonegap cli (5.2.1) and cordova (5.1.1) and my project is on the latest android setup.

I'm on mac running OSX Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by the accidental inclusion of node modules within a bower module in the www directory.

If you're seeing a build error like it's possible you have something in your project that shouldn't be there.

Running

```
<PathToProject>/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b <PathToProject>/platforms/android/build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true --debug
```

Will give you the exact file that's causing the issue.
The output will be something like:

```
10:51:14.394 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] => assets/www/bower_components/pointing_js/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/maxmin/node_modules/gzip-size/node_modules/browserify-zlib/node_modules/pako/test/browser/test.html
10:51:14.395 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] => assets/www/bower_components/pointing_js/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/maxmin/node_modules/gzip-size/node_modules/browserify-zlib/node_modules/pako/test/browser/test.js
10:51:14.395 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] => assets/www/bower_components/pointing_js/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/maxmin/node_modules/gzip-size/node_modules/browserify-zlib/node_modules/pako/test/chunks.js
10:51:14.396 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] => assets/www/bower_components/pointing_js/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/maxmin/node_modules/gzip-size/node_modules/browserify-zlib/node_modules/pako/test/deflate.js
10:51:14.397 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] => assets/www/bower_components/pointing_js/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/maxmin/node_modules/gzip-size/node_modules/browserify-zlib/node_modules/pako/test/deflate_cover.js
10:51:14.397 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] => assets/www/bower_components/pointing_js/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/maxmin/node_modules/gzip-size/node_modules/browserify-zlib/node_modules/pako/test/fixtures/gzip-headers
10:51:14.404 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':packageArmv7Debug'
10:51:14.405 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :packageArmv7Debug FAILED
```